# Issue with SMB API while connecting to remote share folder using Java

Tags: java, smb, nas

artifact : smbj
version : 0.3.0

Able to connect to the server but when it try to access the

```
DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(sambaSharedPath);
```

Below Exception is throwing. Please suggest fix.

```
com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_PATH(3221225662/3221225662): Could not connect to \\SharePatch\
    at com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session.connectTree(Session.java:113)
    at com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session.connectShare(Session.java:98)
    at com.smbj.test.CreateNASFile.upload(CreateNASFile.java:71)
    at com.smbj.test.CreateNASFile.main(CreateNASFile.java:107)
```

Comment: Can you post the full code. What does `sambaSharedPath` look like?

Comment: Thanks Hiery. Issue got resolved after passing shaereName and sharePath separately (We should not pass full combined path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved after passing shaereName and sharePath separately (We should not pass full combined path).